# PHP ob_start and session_start question?

Tags: php

Should I use ob_start() before session_start() or session_start() before ob_start()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really doesn't matter. `session_start()` will not output anything (except for an error if something goes wrong) so the output buffer will not be affected either way. My script runs `session_start()` first simply because it loads that file first (alphabetical order).

To me, this seems like saying 'should I define `$a = 1` or `$b = 2` first?' when in the end `$c = $a + $b` will always be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it matters but I would say ob_start() first since it captures output.