# script does not load while using jquery/ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to add through ajax/jquery a script into a div seconds after the page has loaded. The script itself is from a CPM network and loads a banner.

When I load it right when the page loads, the script is loaded, but if I add it through ajax, the script stays like this:

```
<script>content here...<script>
```

I get the following information after loading it by ajax: "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html"

I searched for some solutions but can't find one that works.

Here is the ajax call:

```
function showAds(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"pub-horizontal.php",
            type:"POST",
            async: false,
            data: {link:link},
            success:function(result){
                $("#p1").html(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is pub-horizontal.php file

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div id="pub-horizontal" class="pub-horizontal">
    <?php

        $url = $_POST['link'];

        if(!strpos($url,"article")){
            include("****-horizontal.php");
        }else{
            include("cpmfun-horizontal.php");
        }



    ?>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried to output something into the console using the script and it worked! Seems like that the problem is with the script of the CPM network that does not load after the document has loaded...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the code surrounding (including) your ajax call

Comment: I added the ajax call as you requested ;)

Comment: Does #p1 exists? What you get in result variable from ajax call?

Comment: Yes, #p1 exists. There is only the problem with that particular script not loading... All the others are ok.

Comment: Lets take a look at your php

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `header("content-type: application/javascript");`

at the top of the php file

Comment: I get the following error: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ************article.php:3) in ***********article.php on line 4 AND I know that I need to add it right after the <?php without any blank line between.

Comment: @Th3lmuu90 Would `ob_start()` help with that? [Ref1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450990/why-ob-start-must-come-ahead-of-session-start-to-work-in-php) [Ref2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122343/php-ob-start-and-session-start-question)

Comment: perhaps try with jquery load instead `$(#p1).load('pub-horizontal.php',{link:link});`

Comment: @gibberish not really... I added ob_start after and before header and the error continues... and I have session_start after the header and ob_start()

Comment: @andrew not even with jquery load. I always get the following information: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: